# incoming call broadcast receiver is not working on actual phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

```
public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String phoneNumber;
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null){
            phoneNumber=bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            if(phoneNumber!=null){

                DatabaseHelper databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper();
                Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
                ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put("incoming_number", phoneNumber);
                contentValues.put("date",String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DATE)+"-"+c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"-"+c.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
                contentValues.put("time", String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
                databaseHelper.addContact(contentValues);
                databaseHelper.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Above code works fine in emulator, but on actual device it is not working any more. In my application I don't want to include any activity, so how to solve the problem.

Comment: what do you mean not working? crashing? not calling the onReceive ?? what??

Comment: @StinePike broadcast receiver does not invoke so that values are not inserted in database

Comment: @StinePike on phone it does not crash

Comment: it may not be added to database for many reason other than broadcast call. debug and check whether your onreceive is called..

Comment: @StinePike on emulator it add data to database so no issue with database

Comment: do you know how to debug? debug and check if onReceive is called. I am not asking what happened in emulator

Comment: @StinePike when i debug onReceive never call

Answer (score 0):

Its not seen in your snippet, but as your code is working in the emulator you must have registered this listener either statically or on the fly.

I far as i can remember, you need to manually start your application once in order to receive broadcasts [ api version 3 onwards]. So if your emulator and phone versions differ [phone higher than 3] start the application from launcher drawer and then try again.
This was added as a security feature, so that only those apps which user had manually started receive the broadcasts.

Comment: can you please guide me how to do that?

Comment: Have some activity in your app, when app gets installed, open that first by launching it from drawer. If rest of your code is okay, you should start receiving broadcasts on app running in physical phone as well. Also to isolate the database part, write something to logcat inur onRecieve code